# Using actions of Caliburn.Micro

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, caliburn.micro

I want to use actions actions of caliburn.micro.
I'm using this namespaces

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
```

and

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

But when I want to use it in code I get message that name ActionMessage doesn't exist in namespace "http://www.caliburnproject.org". so how I can use actions?

```
 <Button x:Name="ShowName">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowNameAction" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/277

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware, unfortunately this source doesn't help

Comment: nothing on codeplex will be up to date, since everything has shifted over to GitHub and SO for questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"`.

Maybe there might be compatibility issues with the versions.

Have a look at this [Porting a WP8 to Caliburn Micro](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/porting-a-windows-phone-8-0-application-to-caliburn-micro-2-0-2/)

Hope it helps!